# How to control the image not to move out from the imageView?

Tags: android, image, imageview, zooming, move

I use onTouch to move a image in the imageView, But unfortunately it will move out the screen .So Is there a better way to control that if the image bounds touch the border,then we can stop it move out?

Comment: What code do you use to move the image inside the ImageView?

Comment: I have the same problem, how do you manage this please give me a sample

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding your question. But if I've interpreted your question correct, you currently have a draggable imageview and you want to make sure that the image´s borders don't go outside of the screen? The only way to stop that from happening is to check whether or not the image bounds go outside of the screen. Below code is NOT complete, it will just help you on the way. finalHeight and finalWidth will now hold your imageView´s actual size on screen (I.e The actual image´s size in the imageview).

```
int windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
final ImageView mImage= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mImage);

int finalHeight, finalWidth;
ViewTreeObserver vto = mImage.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        finalHeight = mImage.getMeasuredHeight();
        finalWidth = mImage.getMeasuredWidth();
        return true;
    }
});

mImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) mImage.getLayoutParams();
                    switch(event.getAction())
                    {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   
                                                    break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                         int x_cord = (int)event.getRawX();
                         int y_cord = (int)event.getRawY();

                         if(x_cord>windowwidth){x_cord=windowwidth;}
                         if(y_cord>windowheight){y_cord=windowheight;}

                         layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 10; // Set these to co-responding values
                         layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 10; // Set these to co-responding values
                         mImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                         break;
                    default:
                         break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
        });
```

This may help you on the way =)

Comment: I am sorry for my poor English, I don't want to move imageView,I want to drag the drawable in the imageView.Thanks a lot, I have solved it with the rect of  drawable